# TFS Multi-configuration with different set of variables

Tags: tfs, multi-configuration

I need to deploy the same project and the same version on different environments. Each environment requires its own values for the given variables, e.g. ENV1 requires var1a, var1b, var1c and ENV2 requires var2a, var2b and var2c. You cannot have a combination var1a and var2b. That means that I need to run exactly the same build but with different set of variables.

There are about 20 variables and 50 environments so changing them manually 1000 times per version is not exactly an option.
I can create a different build definition for each set of variables' values and end up with 50 definitions, but that seems a little bit redundant. Not to mention in case I want to remove a step, I will need to update 50 definitions.

Can I somehow link a variable group to a build configuration and make the build definition switch the values automatically?

Comment: [Octopus Deploy](https://octopus.com/) is your friend

Comment: Are you using Release Management? Reading this I think you're trying to deploy from your build which isn't a good idea.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into that

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to not use another tool like Octopus Deploy (regradless that you could achieve the needed work with it), and stick to your TFS, assuming that you are on TFS 2015 or higher version already, you could probably take advantage of the [creating and deploying release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/create-deploy-releases)  using [Release Definitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/) through the Release Management and use [Custom Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/variables?tabs=batch) to have the same variable to have different value based on the Environment you are going to use it for.